# How to prevent database to search for old objects?

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a Django app which uses Postgresql as the database. I store some objects that have a datetime field. In my queries I usually want to fetch the objects that are stored in last day or last week, so older objects are of no importance for me.

I cannot delete the older objects because I sometimes want to fetch all the data.

I want to optimize the app.
Is there any way to just search the data stored in the last day and not search for the other data?

**Edit:**

Imagine there are so many records, say 1 million, and only small amount of them are for today. If I use `Model.objects.filter(datetime_field__gte=last_week)`, does the database check all the records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query filtering on the DateTime field.

```
import datetime


last_week = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
Model.objects.filter(datetime_field__gte=last_week)
```

Be sure to check the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: If for example there are for example 20,000 records in the database, and say 1000 of them are for today, does this method check all the 20,000 records?

Comment: Yes, Postgres MUST check every row. How do you expect it know the whether a column satisfies your criteria without checking it. You can create an index on date column and then perhaps it would only need to check the index, but there would be a 1:1 between the table and the index. (Actually not quite true. You could go through the herculean task of creating a daily partition and specifying that partition(s) in the query, but that negates the ability to query unknown date ranges.)

Comment: @AK12 As Belayer mentioned above (and he's right), Postgres will check all rolls. You can speed up the query by adding an index to your DateTime as Belayer mentioned but the query will run through ALL your data.

Answer (score 0):

create a new input query2 for example

```
def SearchW(request):
    serchedWl = Modal.objects.all()
    query1= request.GET.get('query1') #main query
    query2= request.GET.get('query2') #last week
    if query1:
        serchedWl =serchedWl.filter(Q(field__contains=query1))
    if query2:
        serchedWl =serchedWl.filter(Q(datetime_field__contains=query2))
    context={
        'title':'your page',
        'serchedWl': serchedWl, 
    }
    return render(request,'to your page .html',context)
```

don't forget the tag is serchedWl